# Вызвать метод в определенном состоянии

Tags: java, android

И так, хочу реализовать следующее:
При входе в приложение выполняется метод `startP();` , после выполнения этого метода открывается второе Activity, во втором Activity есть кнопка, по нажатию которой должно вернуть в первую, главную Activity, НО , теперь не должен выполнятся метод `startP();` , а должен выполнится метод `blabla();` . Метод `startP();` может выполнится снова в случае если пользователь вышел из приложения  и вошел снова.

Я пытался реализовать это, у меня получилось вот что:

Заходим в приложение -> Начинают выполнятся методы `startP();` и `blabla();` -> бросает на второе Activity -> Нажимаю кнопку -> Переходим в первое Activity -> Начинают выполнятся методы `startP();` и `blabla();` и так далее..

Код первого Activity:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);
    startP();
}

protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    blabla();
  }
```

Код второго Activity:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bOk:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: что то не видно хоть каких то попыток решить вашу проблему в том, что вы пытаетесь реализовать :)

Comment: @pavlofff не понял вас

Answer (score 1):

Проблема несколько сложнее, чем может показаться на первый взгляд. Из-за особенностей жизненного цикла **Activity**.

Если вас устроит выполнения **startP**() при запуске приложения, если оно до этого не было запущено или было прибито системой/пользователем, то вам надо:

1. В метод **startP**() поместить запись в переменную **Activity** некоего **boolean** значения, показывающего, что **startP**() был уже вызван и проверять его перед исполнением кода этого метода.
2. Реализовать сохранение этого значения в **onSaveInstanceState**() **Activity** и его восстановление в **onRestoreInstanceState**() или в **onCreate**()
3. То же можно и для **blabla**() реализовать для предотвращения повторного его вызова при, например, смене ориентации экрана.

Comment: Если речь идет о `Bundle`, то, думаю, его значения не нужно сохранять, при пересоздании активити он не уничтожается. Сохранение состояний активити само использует `Bundle` для этого.

Comment: Ну, я типа имел в виду запись значения в поле активити и его последующее сохранение в onSaveInstanceState... Да, выразился не совсем так, как хотел, ща поправлю)

Answer (score 1):

Вы могли бы из второй активити слать с интентом какой то флаг и проверять в первом, получен он или нет - если да, то пришили из второй активти, если нет - то первый запуск.Как то так:

первое активити:

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        Intent intent= getIntent();
        if (intent.getBooleanExtra("isReturn", false)) startP();
    }
```

второе активити:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.bOk:
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
        intent.putExtra("isReturn",true);
        startActivity(intent);
      break;
    }
}
```

Comment: не могли бы вы на примере показать как `из второй активити слать с интентом какой то флаг и проверять в первом, получен он или нет - если да, то пришили из второй активти, если нет - то первый запуск`